# Visual C++ 2010 - CL.exe exit code 5

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

When I try to compile my project in Release mode CL.exe exits with code 5. There are no more messages about what's going wrong.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Could you paste the whole ouput log?

Comment: A guess: error code 5 means "Access is denied" with WINAPI. Do you have write access to the directory where the release files are to be built?

Comment: 5 is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(VS.85).aspx

Comment: maybe you have already an instance of the output .exe file which is currently running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, system error code 5 aka [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28VS.85%29.aspx) can be because of a few problems.

1. You may already have the .exe open, in which case just close the .exe and try to run again.
2. You may not have write access to where ever you are writing. This is a strange predicament, though to ensure you do, either go to the folder and set the permissions to write, or starting Visual Studio in administrator mode may work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. In my case i have installed Visual Studio Community for trial. This trial expired. 
My solution:

deinstall Visual Studio Community
install Visual C++ Tools (download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe)