# Visual Studio 2013 CL.exe not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, cl.exe

I installed my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on my D: Drive (not my windows drive), as i could'nt change it during setup.

So i wanted to continue on a project, and when compiling it says "CL.exe" not found.

I tried the .bat in the /VC/bin folder, and also setting up the PATH variable on my own as some "problem threads" supposed. But nothing helped: still "TRACKER: Fehler TRK0005"

and "C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.targets(147,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 5.

:/

Can someone help me?

Comment: `"CL.exe" exited with code 5` means CL.exe is found otherwise it wouldn't exit :P see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962196/visual-c-2010-cl-exe-exit-code-5 for example. Also: don't even bother setting up the PATH yourself, I doubt you are going to get that right. Use the supplied 'VS2013 Command Prompt'

Comment: I'm more than certain by now, that it's because it's installed on d. But hes looking for all the dependent files on c (as it's supposed to be installed on the system drive). It works all fine on my Laptop where i just installed it on the systemdrive and did the rest exactly the same.